# huge memory load in keras lstm (timesteps x features)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, lstm, sentiment-analysis

There are 10000 files composed by 200000 words (each one). I have put all words from all files in a python list. The **np.reshape** is (10000, 200000, 256). 256 is because of an **one hot encoding**. The main problem in this approach is memory, because **input_shape** = (200000, 256). I do not know if an inversion is possible, like **np.reshape** (10000, 256, 200000) and **input_shape** = (256, 200000), because everything is in the same list and I do not have a certain if the keras is splitting each sample correctly or the words of each file are shuffling with words from others files, returning wrong classification in the end.

Comment: Can I double-check: each file has 200,000 words in it? But your total vocabulary is only 256 different words?  (That is what "256 is because of an one hot encoding" would imply... or did you mean you are using word-embeddings with a dimension of 256?)

Answer (score 0):

stem words,

find unique words,

remove stop words,

read this tutorial;

https://machinelearningmastery.com/clean-text-machine-learning-python/